# Multiple sequential sink in flink dataset API

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink

I am trying to implement a batch data processing pipeline in flink, where i need to

1. Read a file with more than 90million rows
2. Perform some transformations
3. Publish the data in elastic search
4. Publish a notification with some meta data to downstream systems that job is completed and they can read read out of elasticsearch

Problem 1 : I did not find any easy way to publish data to elasticsearch, there is no out of the box output function provided in flink dataset API to publish data to elasticsearch only options i could find were writing to a file or implementing a custom function

Problem 2: To resolve problem-1 i am publishing data to elasticsearch in a map function. Map operator is defined with parallelism 4. I am defining an output function with parallelism 1 but i will not know when are all the operator instances done processing so that i can publish the message downstream.

I don't want to send notification for each event on topic but a single message on topic confirming that all 90million rows are processed and consumers can now query data from elasticsearch.

Is there any way to resolve this ?

Secondly writing elasticsearch in a map function does not seems right its not a transformation but a output, as i need 2 sequential sinks here, is there any cleaner way to do it ?
Below is the sample flow diagram

[image]

Comment: For problem 1, why can't you use this connector: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html ?

Comment: @Val this connector is available only for datastream not for dataset (batch), and i do not see any way to convert dataset to datastream.  https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/batch/#data-sinks

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approche to solve your case is;

1. Load File to Table
2. Convert Table to [DataStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/common.html#convert-a-table-into-a-datastream) , you can manipulate the data using the table API or after the conversion.
3. Insert Data to elastic using the [elastic Connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html)

If you want to understand if the job has finished you can check the [numRecordsOutPerSecond](https://flink.apache.org/news/2019/02/25/monitoring-best-practices.html) metrics.

Comment: Seems the right approach, however any advice for 2nd problem where I want to execute 2 sink operations in sequence such that when elastic sink for all records and then send a message on topic, which notifies downstream systems or a job completion hook which can send notification

Comment: That would mean working outside of flink job, I was hoping that there would be some way within the flink job pipeline to allow me to send data via es-sink then send a notification via kafka-sink

Comment: @AmbujJauhari please accept the answer if you found it useful